# How to pass $_POST value across more than 2 page

Tags: php, jquery, post

How to pass $_POST value across more than 2 page

Lets say I have 4 php pages.

```
Register, Select Service, Select Package, Complete

Page 1 is Register.php
Page 2 is Select_Service.php
Page 3 is Select_Package.php
Page 4 is Complete.php
```

I wanna pass $_POST value of Page 1 - Register.php all the way till Page 4 - Complete.php

```
Value are of html Form type and form method is post
```

what is the choice available for me to do so, I know I can use $_SESSION but it will cause issue as I use back button on my post, so session is omitted out.

Is there other way, I know I can also set hidden field and pass through but is there a more neat way to do so.

**Thanks for helping!**

Comment: `I know I can use $_SESSION but it will cause issue as I use back button on my post, so session is omitted out. ` - How is session omitted out?

Comment: sounds like you know the two options, sessions and hidden form fields

Comment: The options you mention are the ones I would suggest! With the $_SESSION option, would it be fixed by stopping the browser from caching the page?

Comment: You could also set cookies on Select_service.php, and retrieve them on the following steps. If you press the back button, the cookies will still be there unless you overwrite them on purpose.